# Slider Revolution chrome Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: google-chrome, video, revolution-slider

Slider Revolution video not play in chrome its return

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause() [image]